# How do I open an ASP.NET empty web application template in C# express?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates

Programmers!!!

I'm learning c# from a book and would like to open a template such the one pictured from visual studio at the top however I only have the options from the c# menu pictured at the bottom.  Is there a way to download or to manually create the same effect?  Thanks!!!

[image: Visual Studio]

[image: Visual C# Express]

Comment: +1 Voting this question up. Even though it is a small problem, The question is written very clearly and i seriously respect people who study themselves with books.

Comment: Thanks...  Learning from a book is the way to go for me, I want a practical working knowledge of the language (vs theoretical).  It's definately tougher than a classroom but hopefully will work out just as well...

Comment: Totally Agree. books will help. But practicing yourself is more important. Good Luck. and come back to SO with interesting questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft provide Visual Web Developer Express for web application development. C# Express is used for desktop development. The paid for version is not split up like the Express versions are.

You can download Visual Web Developer Express from http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express although today being the day it is (release day) you could go for the newer version http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#express-web.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the great answers, I downloaded VS 2012 for web.  Good to have the latest and greatest!  I guess I posted on the right day since it is release day!  Below is the screenshot from VS 2012 for web...

[image: Visual Studio Express for web]

Answer (score 1):

Install this: [Visual Web Developer 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it isn't available in Visual C# 2010 Express, however it is in [Visual Web Developer 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express), and you can still use it while learning C#.